# GParted error message: A partition can not end (156016640) after the end of the device (%2)

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, gparted, resize

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to increase the size of the volume `sdb2`. When trying to reduce the size of the extended partition using GParted live, I got this error message.

```
Could not add this operation to the list
A partition cannot end (153767936) after the end of the device (%2)
```

[image]

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disklabel type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0xfa04408e

Device    Boot  Start    End       Sectors   Size      Id  Type 
/dev/sdb1           2048  15624191  15622144    7.5G   82  Linux swap / Solaris 
/dev/sdb2 *     15624192  93749247  78125056   37.3G   83  Linux 
/dev/sdb3       93751294 468860927 375109634  178.9G    5  Extended 
/dev/sdb5      156018688 468860927 312842240  149.2G   83  Linux
```

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are using, however Ubuntu's `gparted` doesn't have a Debian logo on it, so I'm betting you are using a non-Ubuntu OS.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu only are on-topic here.

Comment: Sorry..I forgot to mention that i am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: <p>Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfa04408e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048  15624191  15622144   7.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb2  *     15624192  93749247  78125056  37.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3        93751294 468860927 375109634 178.9G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       156018688 468860927 312842240 149.2G 83 Linux</p>

Comment: fdisk output looks ok so far. I think it's a problem with the version of gparted you're using, do you use a recent version of Gparted live? You could also try to use your Ubuntu installer (includes Gparted) and try that one.

Comment: @mook765 I have tried with both gparted-live-1.1.0-1-i686.iso and gparted-live-1.1.0-1-amd64.iso. I'm having same type of error from both Images.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/-/issues/86

Comment: @mook765 thank you so much...it worked

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error when resizing or moving a partition lies in the calculation of the partition limits according to one of these options: Cylinder/MiB/None. Change the *Align to:* dropdown selection to *None* and the same operation works without errors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You saved mi time.